# Bash: Retrieve fields from complicated XML file

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I tried to retrieve some fields from an XML file with a complicated structure using shell commands like sed, egrep, awk but it failed.

Here is the structure of my file file.xml (it's repeated many times with different values):

```
<Task ID="186155128" Name="Partner: test" Active="1" NextEID="14" AR="0">
        <Schedules>
            <Schedule OnlyUntilFirstSuccess="0" FailIfNoSuccessInSched="0" RunEvenIfNotif="0">
                <Days>
                    <DayOfWeek>Monday</DayOfWeek>
                    <DayOfWeek>Tuesday</DayOfWeek>
                    <DayOfWeek>Wednesday</DayOfWeek>
                    <DayOfWeek>Thursday</DayOfWeek>
                    <DayOfWeek>Friday</DayOfWeek>
                    <DayOfWeek>Saturday</DayOfWeek>
                    <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
                </Days>
                <Frequency>
                    <Interval StartTime="00:00" EndTime="23:59" EveryMinutes="15"/>
                </Frequency>
            </Schedule>
        </Schedules>
        <Destination HostID="1027635962" Type="AS2" UseDefPartner="1" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" Filename="[OrigName]" RequestMDN="1" RequestSigned="0" />
        <Source HostID="165429109" Type="siLock" FolderID="" FolderType="-1" FolderName="home/test" FileMask="*.*" DeleteOrig="1" NewFilesOnly="0" SearchSubdirs="0" Unzip="0" />

</Task>

<MyID="1027635962" Host1="myhost" DefPartnerURL="https://site.site.com" Password="!s!f7xtVc=="/>
<FID="165429109" DotNET="1" Name="mytest" Host2="testy.com" Port="443" />
```

I want to get the output:    Name;HostID;FolderName;Host1;Host2

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Comment: Show a vaild XML file. Please add your desired output to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you, please see the edit

Comment: An XML file isn't actually valid unless it has a root element. No root element is shown here, nor any joint parent showing how a `Task` is joined with the `MyID` or `FID` elements from which you're intending to retrieve other content. Unless your source file isn't *really* XML (and itself can't be parsed), you'll need to ensure that your sample shown here is valid.

Comment: Also, `<MyId="..."`/>` isn't valid -- every attribute needs to have its own name distinct from the element that contains it.

Comment: @GreenX, the content added via the edit doesn't make your intended output clear at all. For instance, by `Name; HostID`, I **assume** that you mean the task name, but lots of things have names -- the `FID` has a name, for instance -- so which one is correct is unclear. Similarly, is `HostID` the *source* HostID? The *destination* HostID? Maybe what you really meant there was the *task* ID? That's why **literal** examples are important rather than pseudocode alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that what you mean instead of the (invalid) string `<MyID="1027635962" Host1="myhost"/>` is instead the (valid) string `<MyID id="1027635962" Host1="myhost"/>`, and of course also assumed that both these datums were part of a valid document, this might look something like:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//Task' \
  -v ./@Name -o ';' \
  -v ./Source/@HostID -o ';' \
  -v ./Destination/@Filename -o ';' \
  -v '//MyID[@id=./Destination/HostID]/@Host1' -o ';' \
  -v '//FID[@id=./Source/HostID]/@Host2' -n \
  <in.xml >out.txt
```